# How to create alert rule for all DBs in a resource group via powershell using foreach loop

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, powershell-5.0

I am looking to create DTU alert rules that will monitor for the DTU going above 90 % for the last 15min.I want to do this for all databases within a resource group.
The idea is to automate the work and save the manual creation of dozens of rules in the GUI and also to avoid running one script for each alert.It must basically create the same alert for for as many databases that you have in the resource group but provide a unique name, see "THAT MUST BE UNIQUE" part in the script

The script I wrote is:

```
#define variable for resource group name by requesting keynoard input

$rg = Read-Host 'Please, input resource group name here (exactly as it is in Azure)'

<#create the array containing databases where alerts are required. The value of v12.0,user corresponds to the kind of resource as to include only the SQL DBs and not the SQL servers#>

$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $rg -and $_.kind -eq "v12.0,user"  } | select -expandpropert resourceid

#loop through the array and create the alert rule for each DB

foreach($resource in $resources){Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroup $rg -location "Central US" -targetresourceid $resource -Name "THAT MUST BE UNIQUE" -MetricName "dtu_consumption_percent" -Operator "GreaterThan" -Threshold 90 -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:15:00")) -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" -verbose -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners -CustomEmails "putemail@here.com")}
```

The problem is that IT CREATES ONLY ONE ALERT and then errors out with the following (which persumably points to an issue with the -name value not being unique):

```
Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Can not update target resource id during
update., Code: BadRequest, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: Bad Request
At C:\Users\CreateDTUalertsFORallDBv2.ps1:11 char:34
+ ... $resources){Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroup $rg -location " ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Alerts.AddAzureRmMetricAlertRuleCommand
```

Can you please advise what is going wrong and how can I make it work as to create a DTU metric for each DB in the resource group following the parameters form the script ?I am also curious how can I populate the "`-name`" parameter from the above script with something unique to the DB where the alert will be working (ideally with the resource name value that can be fed from the Get-AzureRmResource commandlet which is right before the foreach loop in the script).

If I try to populate the -name parameter with the RESOURCENAME of the DB using the below script :

```
#define variable for resource group name by requesting keynoard input

$rg = Read-Host 'Please, input resource group name here (exactly as it is in Azure)'

#create the array containing databases where alerts are required

$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $rg -and $_.kind -eq "v12.0,user"  } | select -expandpropert resourceid

#loop through the array and create the alert rule for each DB

foreach($resource in $resources){$resourcename = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $rg -Resourceid $resource).resourcename;Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroup $rg -location "Central US" -targetresourceid $resource -Name $resourcename -MetricName "dtu_consumption_percent" -Operator "GreaterThan" -Threshold 90 -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:15:00")) -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" -verbose -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners -CustomEmails "Client-DestinationHotels@hhogdev.com")}
```

It errors about the name not being unique, see error below :

```
    Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\ttest.ps1:11 char:234
+ ...  "Central US" -targetresourceid $resource -Name $resourcename -Metric ...
+                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Alerts.AddAzureRmMetr
   icAlertRuleCommand

Get-AzureRmResource : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Users\ttest.ps1:11 char:51
+ ... urcename = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $rg -Resourceid $r ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmResource], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.Ge
```

Comment: the error suggest there is an update on the resource already, try modifying the name dynamically?

Comment: use part of the $resource variable + fixed suffix. say `-name "$($resource.name)-ALERT"`

Comment: that didn't work , I think it tried to pickup the resource ID from the $resources array

Comment: well, it contains `/` and is a bit too long, probably, also you are not posting the error you are getting, try using name or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey , here is how I did it. I had to dynamically pass the resource name but after cutting it after the first slash (the resource name values had a slash in the string which was problematic)

```
#define variable for resource group name by requesting keyboard input

$rg = Read-Host 'Please, input resource group name here (exactly as it is in Azure)'

<#create the array containing databases where alerts are required. The value of v12.0,user corresponds to the kind of resource as to include only the SQL DBs and not the SQL servers#>

$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $rg -and $_.kind -eq "v12.0,user"  } | select resourcename,resourceid

#loop through the array and create the alert rule for each DB

foreach($resource in $resources){$alertname=$resource.resourcename.Substring($resource.resourcename.IndexOf('/')+1);Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule -ResourceGroup $rg -location "centralus" -targetresourceid $resource.resourceid -Name $alertname -MetricName "dtu_consumption_percent" -Operator "GreaterThan" -Threshold 90 -WindowSize $([TimeSpan]::Parse("00:15:00")) -TimeAggregationOperator "Average" -verbose -Actions $(New-AzureRmAlertRuleEmail -SendToServiceOwners -CustomEmails "Client-address@domain.com")}
```

Answer (score -1):

The exact DTU alert you are trying to create has been created step-by-step on [this](http://www.mikefal.net/2016/08/23/creating-alerts-for-azure-sql-database-with-powershell/) article.

Comment: I think you are missing the point , the question here is not how to create ONE rule against ONE db,but instead it is about using foreach loop that will create the alert for as many DB's as you have in the resource group (in my case i have 18).If you read carefully the beginning of the question ,I stressed on the importance to automate it and make it work for all DBs in the resource group and not only for one DB as your suggestion does.

Comment: Look at the function provided on the next resource: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3606/automate-retrieving-sql-azure-bacpacs-with-powershell/. That is a foreach that retrieve all databases per SQL Azure Database server. I have not seen that per resource group.

Comment: Thanks Alberto ,but as can be seen above in my script , I can do the DB retrieval per resrouce group here ($resources = Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $rg -and $_.kind -eq "v12.0,user"  } | select -expandpropert resourceid). The question is rather how to populate the -name parameter for the "Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule" with a unique value (ideally the DB's resource name)